# gcroot Collection - element access

Tags: .net, c++, collections, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I'm making bridge from .NET to C++ and using Collection as a public element like this :

```
gcroot<System::Collections::ObjectModel::Collection<BModel::Device ^> ^> Devices;
```

I'm using gcroot because my c++ class is not managed (it's MFC) but I'm having trouble with accessing it. When I am doing :

```
Devices[x]->devicename
```

I've got error :

> Error 6   error C2676: binary '[' : 'gcroot' does not define this
>   operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined
>   operator

So I guess I must access collection element somehow but not with this brackets : [ ]

So how to access gcroot clr collection element ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the member access operator, `->` is overloaded, it appears as if the subscript operator `[]` isn't, unwrap your `gcroot` first.

```
using namespace System::Collections::ObjectModel;
Collection<BModel::Device ^> ^d = Devices;
d[0] //... this should work
```

The above represents an implicit cast (this is why you cannot use `auto`). You can use `static_cast` if you need one-liner:

```
static_cast<Collection<BModel::Device ^> ^>(Devices)[0];
```